# How to play audio using the raw data received in AVCaptureSession?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, playback, avcapturesession

I have been trying to play audio which is received as raw data, in `didOutputSampleBuffer: delegate`. I was able to process the video data, however I have no idea how to process audio data, Can anyone please guide me in a right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have processed the raw audio data using AudioUnit method. I am not sure it is the best way, but it worked somewhat.